# Unity reduces the number of available OpenMP threads

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, unity-game-engine, openmp

I use OpenMP in a shared android library. There is a sample method that just checks the number of CPUs and the max number of threads.

```
int maxThreads = omp_get_max_threads();
int numProcs = omp_get_num_procs();
```

When I call this method from a basic android application (AppCompatActivity), both values are set to 8 on the device with Qualcomm Snapdragon 855 CPU (8 cores).

```
maxThreads = 8;
numProc = 8;
```

When I try to call this method from a Unity application, the returned numbers of max threads and procs are 2.

```
maxThreads = 2;
numProc = 2;
```

Why the max threads number in the Unity application is less than in the basic app? Is there a way to increase the number of parallel threads that are actually used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which OpenMP implementation you are using, which would certainly be useful to know.

However, *assuming* that Android behaves like Linux at this level, then what is probably happening is that Unity is setting the process' affinity mask (see [`sched_{get,set}affinity(...)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_getaffinity), which reflects the `logicalCPU`s that the process should use.
The OpenMP runtime almost certainly consults that to determine the number of threads it makes sense to create.

On Linux a process can  affinitize a thread to a `logicalCPU` which is outside its incoming affinity mask, but that is certainly bad behaviour, and may lead to poor performance, since, fundamentally,  your process is at the bottom of the pile and should accept what it is told to do by higher level schedulers.

To be sure you could write a function to print the affinity mask, then you can see what is happening. Alternatively the OpenMP implementation may have an envirable that will cause it to tell you what it's doing. (e.g. Try `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose` if using the Intel or LLVM runtime.)

Comment: The affinity mask is definitely may be a reason of a such behaviour.
Thanks for a suggestion. I will try to print the affinity mask to check this out.
I am using OpenMP version 5.0 which comes within android ndk v21.

Comment: OpenMP 5.0 is a specification, not a compiler. There are many different compilers which implement OpenMP 5.0, whose runtimes may all do different things, since OpenMP 5.0 does not say anything about affinity masks (since they are a Linux specific things, an the specification is applicable more widely than that). I *guess* you're using GCC, but you haven't told us.

Comment: I am using clang, not gcc.

Comment: In which case if you can set envirables, setting KMP_AFFINITY=verbose will show you what the OpenMP runtime is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Unity tries to set the affinity mask. It enables all power-hungry CPUs (BIG). There are four such cores on the device where I've tested. But actually the system allows enabling only two of them. As a result I can only use two OpenMP threads.